# How to add a webview in html5 hybrid app like we add webview in native apps?

Tags: html

How to add a webview in html5 hybrid app like we add webview in native apps

Pls dont get confused with the wrapping of html5 app within a webview and adding it as a native app.

What i need is a web view to be added in my html5 app where a url content is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the content of another url within your page, just use an `iframe`:

```
<body>
    <p>My stuff</p>
    <iframe src="url_to_load"></iframe>
</body>
```

Have in account that `WebView` is a class of the Cocoa framework, which is written in objective-c and allows you to build Mac applications. You can't use this with Html

Comment: Was tryin  to use iframe.. but some pages get opened and some web pages lik google show a blank screen. is that a problem with iframe?

Comment: That is because of CORS. In short, you can't call a certain domain from a different domain. If the server you want to access is yours, you can modify this behavior setting some HTTP headers. Take a look at this document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control